# Reading and storing the data in reverse order in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have copied 2 column data to a file. Since the cluster key of my_date is set to return in descending order

```
     echo "copy home.admin (id,my_date) to 'myOutputFile';" > copyInputs.cql
```

myOutputFile -

```
     TEST1,2015-01-01 15:00:00+0000
     TEST1,2014-09-04 14:00:00+0000
     4.VOD,2015-08-18 04:00:00+0000
     4.VOD,2015-06-26 04:00:00+0000
     4.VOD,2015-05-13 04:00:00+0000
     000TEST8,2015-11-19 05:00:00+0000
```

First column is id and second is my_date. I wanted to read the data in reverse order for each id. So the output should be like this-

```
     TEST1,2014-09-04 14:00:00+0000
     TEST1,2015-01-01 15:00:00+0000
     4.VOD,2015-05-13 04:00:00+0000
     4.VOD,2015-06-26 04:00:00+0000
     4.VOD,2015-08-18 04:00:00+0000
     000TEST8,2015-11-19 05:00:00+0000
```

After getting this output am preparing an update statement to populate one new column my_rev.my_rev will start from 100 for eaach id and increment until i find a new id.

```
    update home.admin my_rev =100 where id = 'TEST1' and my_date = '2014-09-04 14:00:00+0000';
    update home.admin my_rev =101 where id = 'TEST1' and my_date = '2015-01-01 15:00:00+0000';
    update home.admin my_rev =100 where id = '4.VOD' and my_date = '2015-05-13 04:00:00+0000';
    update home.admin my_rev =101 where id = '4.VOD' and my_date = '2015-06-26 04:00:00+0000';
    update home.admin my_rev =102 where id = '4.VOD' and my_date = '2015-08-18 04:00:00+0000';
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: In your example, none of the IDs have a date which overlaps with a different ID.  Is the output guaranteed to be that way?

Comment: Hi John.. Yes, each id will have unique my_dat a its creation date and time.. So date wise it can match but not at hrs or minutes level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to read the data in reverse order for each id

This prints each `id` in reverse order:

```
$ awk -F, '$1==prev {s=$0 "\n" s; next} { printf "%s",s; s=$0 "\n"; prev=$1} END{printf "%s",s}' infile
TEST1,2014-09-04 14:00:00+0000
TEST1,2015-01-01 15:00:00+0000
4.VOD,2015-05-13 04:00:00+0000
4.VOD,2015-06-26 04:00:00+0000
4.VOD,2015-08-18 04:00:00+0000
000TEST8,2015-11-19 05:00:00+0000
```

How it works:

This script uses two variables.  `prev` contains the ID for the previous line.  `s` contains the lines for the most recent ID in reverse order.

- `-F,`

  This tells awk to use a comma as the field separator.
- `$1==prev {s=$0 "\n" s; next}`

  For lines that have the same ID (field 1, denoted `$1`), this adds the new line to the beginning of variable `s`.  The rest of the commands are skipped and awk jumps to the `next` line.
- `printf "%s",s; s=$0 "\n"; prev=$1`

  If we get here, we are starting a new ID.  In this case, we print the lines saved in `s` from the previous ID.  We update `s` with the current line and we set `prev` to the current `ID`.
- `END{printf "%s",s}`

  After we reach the end of the file, we print `s` for the last ID.

#### Alternative

If you want to do a more complex re-ordering, this invokes `sort`, with all of its flexibility, for each `id`, keeping each `id` in its original order:

```
$ awk -F, -v s=sort '$1==prev {print | s; next} {close(s); print | s; prev=$1}' infile
TEST1,2014-09-04 14:00:00+0000
TEST1,2015-01-01 15:00:00+0000
4.VOD,2015-05-13 04:00:00+0000
4.VOD,2015-06-26 04:00:00+0000
4.VOD,2015-08-18 04:00:00+0000
000TEST8,2015-11-19 05:00:00+0000
```

#### Re-formatting

If outfile contains the output of the sorting command above, then run:

```
$ awk -F, '{if ($1==prev)n++; else n=100; prev=$1; printf "update home.admin my_rev =%i where id = '\''%s'\'' and my_date = '\''%s'\'';\n",n,$1,$2}' outfile
update home.admin my_rev =100 where id = 'TEST1' and my_date = '2014-09-04 14:00:00+0000';
update home.admin my_rev =101 where id = 'TEST1' and my_date = '2015-01-01 15:00:00+0000';
update home.admin my_rev =100 where id = '4.VOD' and my_date = '2015-05-13 04:00:00+0000';
update home.admin my_rev =101 where id = '4.VOD' and my_date = '2015-06-26 04:00:00+0000';
update home.admin my_rev =102 where id = '4.VOD' and my_date = '2015-08-18 04:00:00+0000';
update home.admin my_rev =100 where id = '000TEST8' and my_date = '2015-11-19 05:00:00+0000';
```

Comment: for my second part , should i use some loop ?

Comment: Thanks John..am getting the exact output, but on each line ^M is appending..  update home.admin my_rev =100 where id = 'TEST1' and my_date = '2014-09-04 14:00:00+0000^M'; why so?

Comment: ohh i got it.. i need some conversion before that

Comment: I was getting ^M , since i was performing operation on dos  file.. before that i had to perform conersion dos file to unix file. Thanks John for all your help.. cheers

Comment: @okla Glad it worked.  And, yes, good diagnosis: DOS adds those troublesome `^M` characters.

Answer (score 1):

`sort` should do the trick

```
sort -r -t, -k1,2 infile
```

In general, the only option you need is `-r`.

Comment: yes.. indeed it worked.. thanks Michael. but my only concern is second part of the question? cant i use some loop and do some manipulation using sed in order to write update statement for populating my_rev? on each id my_rev value would be 100 and it will increament by 1 until there is another new id

Comment: I just wanted to print the update statement in some file. like i mentioned my post

Comment: @okla This only addresses the sorting part. As for the rest, I can't beat John1024's solution.